# Declare external global variables for glsl validator / webgl / three.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, static-analysis, glsles

I'm building a project with three.js and importing glsl files externally (with glsl-ify-loader) for use in a Three `ShaderMaterial`.

When using `ShaderMaterial`, Three prepends global variables like `projectionMatrix`, `modelViewMatrix` to my shader code pre-compilation when it concats the shader. So when I write my shader all i need is (as a simple example):

```
varying vec3 vNormal;

void main () {
  vNormal = normal;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

... or similar.

My problem is that I'm using the glsl validator on my shader files which subsequently thinks that the pre-declared three variables are undeclared.

In JS, with eslint you could put `/* global aGlobalVariableHere */` to appease the lint gods.

Is there anyway of doing this with the glsl validator? I can't find any resources that suggest how I could go about it.

Comment: what is "the glsl validator"? Is that some library?

Comment: @gman I use vscode with the following:
https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CADENAS.vscode-glsllint

Comment: @gman GLSL Validator is a plugin for some text editors that check your variable usage and report errors from inside the text editor. For instance, if you declare a `vec2` and attempt to access it's `.z` attribute, it'll tell you it's not allowed. [I've used this one for Sublime Text before](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GLSL%20Validator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`THREE.RawShaderMaterial` (see docs)](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/RawShaderMaterial), instead of `ShaderMaterial`. They're identical, except `Raw` doesn't prepend any uniforms or attributes to your shader at all, you have to do it manually. Then your linter will no longer act surprised:

#### Top of vertex shader:

```
precision highp float;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
// ...

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;
// ...
```

You can [read this page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram) to see what uniforms and attributes get automatically added so you can add them yourself if needed in your shader code.

Comment: It's not ideal but itĺl need to do under the circumstances.

Comment: no reason to put `precision highp float;` at the top of a vertex shader. That's the default for vertex shaders.